# Как сделать проверку на запущенный таймер? pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Создаю бота-игру для телеграма. Суть вопроса в том, что когда я нажимаю на кнопку (пример ниже), у меня запускается таймер (человек отправился на задание). После того как таймер заканчивается, я получаю результат. Но если нажимать кнопку два или более раза, то таймер будет создаваться и запускаться снова. У меня есть следующий код:

```
elif message.text == 'Хулиганы':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Разборки начались, возвращайся через 5 секунд!')
    local_time = float(5)
    time.sleep(local_time)
    <..результат..>
```

Я подумал, что перед запуском таймера, нужно делать проверку, если таймер запущен, то выдавать bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уже отправились на задание, дождитесь окончания'). В противном случае выполнять код который представлен выше.

Правда здесь вытекает второй вопрос: как запускать ту же проверку уже из другой кнопки, потому что при нажатии на нее там создается свой индивидуальный таймер?

Comment: Одним из вариантов решения, которое я нашел в гугле было запоминать старт и высчитывать оставшееся время, после делать проверку что если оно не равно 0 то выполнять необходимые действия. Но как в таком случае быть со второй кнопкой, если там при нажатии создается другой таймер.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать класс Timer с нужным поведением вашего таймера. В этом классе создайте булевое поле, которе будет устанавливаться в True, когда таймер запущен. И делайте проверку по этому полю

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!